# JDBC services : staless or stateful

Tags: java, database, jdbc, service

My definition of stateless vs stateful services is:

> Stateless means the state of the service doesn't persist between
>   subsequent requests and response. Each request carries its own user
>   credentials and is individually authenticated.
>
> In stateful each request is known from any prior request. All stateful
>   requests are session-oriented i.e. each request need to know and
>   retain changes made in previous requests.

Do DBMS offer stateful or stateless services ?

Comment: Motivating your downvotes could be a good idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that state-full is the closest match to your definition.

When you open a connection to a database, it holds a session open until the connection is closed.  User credentials are passed only at the creation of the connection and then many requests can be sent in batches. Usually there are options and features that persist in the session.  In SQL Server for example, some `SET` options apply only to that session.  Also, temporary tables created persist only for that session.  Variable declarations only persist for the current batch of the session.

You could however make your requests stateless if you open and close the connection after every request.

Comment: thanks, can you suggest any materials where these kind of concepts are discussed in more depths ? ;)